# how do i get the process arguments using regex?

Tags: regex, command-line-arguments

I have a process args like that:

> -a testa testaa testaaa -b testb testbb -c test-c -d

I want get the result like:

> -a testa testaa testaaa

> -b testb testbb

> -c test-c

> -d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should do the trick:

```
(?<=( |^))-.*?(?=(?<=( |^))-|$)
```

where:

- `(?<=( |^))-` identifies start of each argument which is `-`
- `.*` matches all characters that come after `-`
- `?` makes this matching less greedy
- `(?=(?<=( |^))-|$)` contains the same regex as the first bullet point `(?<=( |^))-` . `$` indicates the end of the string, so in simpler words: `(?=(start of argument) OR (end of string))` .

(refer to [Regex Cheat Sheet](https://cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/))

Comment: This match can't find "The argument value contain -" like -c test-c.

Comment: Please check this edit